# Flask-sqlalchemy many to many relationship data

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a discord like application, but I haven't been able to properly set the relationship. I am using a "members" association table to link the users to a server. I believe that the users and the servers should keep a copy of the relationship so that a user can print all the servers it is connected to and a server can see all the members it has. This is the code I have so far.

```
members = db.Table('members',
    db.Column('member_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('workspace_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('workspace.id')))

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__="user"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    username=db.Column(db.String,nullable=False, unique=True)
    workspaces = db.relationship(
        "Workspace",
        secondary=members,
        primaryjoin=(members.c.workspace_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('members', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')


class Workspace(db.Model):
    __tablename__="workspace"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    workspaceName=db.Column(db.String,nullable=False)
    subgroups=db.relationship("subGroup",backref="workspace",lazy=True)
    code = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    users = db.relationship(
        "User",
        secondary=members,
        primaryjoin=(members.c.member_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('members', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')
```

Do I append from both sides of the relationship or just append once?

Comment: Your usage is not correct. `users = db.relationship(User, secondary=members, backref=db.backref('workspaces', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')` is enough for you.

Comment: @YangHG Thats for the Workspace class right? So I only need to append once like user.members.append(workspace) and it should work?

Comment: In users there is `members.c.workspace_id == id` as primaryjoin condition, but id is Users.id so it doesn't make sense. Likewise in Workspace for member_id.